# Add custom button to contact page layout in lightning which uses custom lightning components

Tags: custom-button, lightning, page-layout, contact, popup

Is there any way to add a custom button to the contact page layout(lightning)? on click of that button a modal popup should popup with my custom lightning components can this be done without visual force page?

Note: the custom lightning component would have some text box and drop downs where the user would input some data. Based on that data we will do an external call when the user clicks save.

Tried with populating lightning component into visual force, is there anyother way i can create a lightning component without embeding in the visualforce page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's possible with the latest winter 17 release (Lightning Quick Action): https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_component_actions.htm

[image]

The Lightning Component which you use should implement

> force:LightningQuickActionWithoutHeader

or

> force:lightningQuickAction